# Counting number of days between 2 dates when exceed in 1 hour add another 1 day

Tags: php, datetime, time, count, difference

I'm having problem when getting the exact number of days. Given I have date/time which consider hours in counting number of days below the code give me zero days

```
$fisrstDate = new DateTime("2018-03-07 04:46:00");
$secondDate = new DateTime("2018-03-07 11:10:00");
$days=$fisrstDate->diff($secondDate)->days;
```

another example is this it should give me 2 days but shows only 1 days my idea is when 24 hours exceed I want to add another 1 days so that it would give me an output of 2 days

```
$fisrstDate = new DateTime("2018-03-07 04:46:00");
$secondDate = new DateTime("2018-03-08 05:00:00");
$days=$fisrstDate->diff($secondDate)->days;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` to get the exact seconds between two time stamps and then convert it to days followed by `ceil` to make it work. Eg:

```
$fisrstDate = strtotime("2018-03-07 04:46:00");
$secondDate = strtotime("2018-03-07 11:10:00");
$days = abs(ceil((abs($fisrstDate - $secondDate)/ (60 * 60 * 24)) - (1 / 24)));
echo $days;
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just `date2 - date1 + 1`?